# Updating latest visit city, region, and country with third party data?

Tags: xdb, experience-profile, geo-location

In the Sitecore Experience Profile -- on the right side of a contact detail page --- you will see a section labeled Latest Visit.

It has fields for City, Region, Country.

I understand that if you purchase the Geo Location service from Sitecore this gets filled in.

If we want to fill it in with another source of data -- is this possible?  I can't seem to find this visit item exposed anywhere under the contact facets.

I am utilizing Sitecore 8.1 Update 2.

Comment: I see the items under Interactions, but they all appear to be read only (i.e. get only, no set).  Obviously, I must be approaching it wrong.   I will update the post with a screenshot when I have actual access to my Sitecore instance on Monday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Answer

It is possible to set this data on your own. It can be done as Gatogordo suggests, using the following code snippet.

```cs
Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.SetGeoData(new WhoIsInformation 
{ City = "Boston", Country= "US", Region = "North America" });
```

However, it's important to know how this data is initially collected in an out-of-the-box scenario.

### Background Information for Sitecore Version 8+

Within Sitecore Analytics, if you do a search in your configs for **UpdateGeoIpData**, you'll find 4 pipelines with a processor to handle retrieving this information.  Each pipeline cares a little differently depending on what's going on. `UpdateGeoIpData()` on the `Interaction` returns a `bool` value depending on the success of gathering GeoIP data.

Those pipelines include:

- **commitSession** `<processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.UpdateGeoIpData, Sitecore.Analytics" patch:source="Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Database.config"/>`

  - This is the last line of defense in the system for making sure that GeoIP data can be recorded.
- **createVisit** `<processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CreateVisits.UpdateGeoIpData, Sitecore.Analytics"/>`

  - This is making sure that the GeoData is set on the Interaction when the visit is first created.
- **ensureClassification** `<processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureClassification.UpdateGeoIpData, Sitecore.Analytics"/>`

  - This processor actually is a precursor processor for other functionality. It's purposes is to set the `ShouldClassificationBeGuessed` argument for the continuation of that pipeline. It utilizes `!Tracker.Current.Interaction.UpdateGeoIpData();` as it's conditional statement. There is a side effect that in the envent the `VisitData.GeoData` is `null`, it will go ahead and attempt to set the geographical information. If the GeoData is present, it returns a fast **true**.
- **startTracking** `<processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartTracking.UpdateGeoIpData, Sitecore.Analytics"/>`

  - This processor initially populates the GeoData inSession Interaction on `Tracker.Current.Session`.

Specifically, these pipeline processes utilize `Session.Interaction.UpdateGeoIpData(Timespan)`.  Also important to note that **Interaction** is actually based off of `CurrentInteraction` which is an abstract class.  There are ***four*** out-of-the-box implementations of this class, of which `CurrentVisitContext` is most commonly used:

[image]

> Unfortunately, `CurrentVisitContext` is ***NOT*** a class that can
>   easily be extended or overridden through Sitecore configuration
>   patching.

#### A Closer Look at the Start Tracking Processor

```cs
  public class UpdateGeoIpData : StartTrackingProcessor
  {
    public override void Process(StartTrackingArgs args)
    {
      Assert.IsNotNull((object) Tracker.Current, "Tracker.Current is not initialized");
      Assert.IsNotNull((object) Tracker.Current.Session, "Tracker.Current.Session is not initialized");
      if (Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction == null)
        return;
      Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.UpdateGeoIpData();
    }
  }
```

Notice it's a pretty simple processor. There is also an Expiry option for location data. Out of the box, the Expiry is turned off (hence `TimeSpan.MaxValue`). However, this is an option.

#### Rolling Your Own - Overriding Default Functionality

To override default functionality and seed your own Geographical Data, I would create processors of your own, mimicking the 4 processors mentioned above. This would ensure that your custom implementation is not confused with the out-of-the-box.

An Example

```cs
  public class CustomGeoIpData : StartTrackingProcessor
  {
    public override void Process(StartTrackingArgs args)
    {
      Assert.IsNotNull((object) Tracker.Current, "Tracker.Current is not initialized");
      Assert.IsNotNull((object) Tracker.Current.Session, "Tracker.Current.Session is not initialized");
      if (Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction == null)
        return;
      Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.SetGeoData(new WhoIsInformation { City = "Boston", Country= "US", Region = "North America" });
    }
  }
```

By setting it here in `startTracking` pipeline or `createVisit` pipeline, all other instances, which utilize `UpdateGeoIpData()`, will be ignored. This is because the very first thing `UpdateGeoIpData()` does is a check to see if VistiData.GeoData is set, which `SetGeoData()` does directly.

```cs
public override bool UpdateGeoIpData(TimeSpan timeout)
{
  VisitData visitData = this.visitData;
  if (visitData.GeoData != null)
    return true;

  ...  snipped code ....

  return true;
}
```

Lastly, you can also run `SetGeoIpData()` during the course of a visit through code, to overwrite the data previously set.

Comment: I have this code:
`WhoIsInformation whois = new WhoIsInformation();
      whois.City = serviceData.city;
      whois.MetroCode = serviceData.metro_code.ToString();
      whois.Region = serviceData.region_name;
      whois.PostalCode = serviceData.zip_code;
      whois.Country = serviceData.country_name;
      whois.Latitude = serviceData.latitude;
      whois.Longitude = serviceData.longitude;
      Tracker.Current.Interaction.SetGeoData(whois);`

I am getting an Object reference not set to an instance error on the last line?

Comment: Is Tracker.Current = null?

Comment: Above this code I call var contact = Tracker.Current.Session.Contact; and that works fine so not sure how it could become suddenly null?

Comment: I would need to see the stack trace of the error. Might be coming from serviceData.

Comment: find me on Slack or shoot me an email.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure Pete will elaborate further on this, but to get you going already: the property on the `Interaction` is indeed only a getter, but there is a function called `SetGeoData`. This would end up in this:

```cs
Tracker.Current.Interaction.SetGeoData(new WhoIsInformation { City = "", Country= "", Region = "" });
```

Found some code [here](https://github.com/edvineshagh/LaunchSitecoreTrafficGen/blob/master/LaunchSitecoreTrafficGen/ContactUpdate.aspx.cs) that fills the geo data (amongst others) that you can use as well.